# Accessing class present in a different folder in Python

Tags: python

I want to access a configuration class in my script. The configuration class is present in a folder which is one level up and then in a separate folder. My folder and file organization is below:

```
.
├── configs
│   ├── config.json
│   ├── config_manager.py
│   └── __init__.py
└── simulaton_scripts
    └── test_script.py
```

**Requirement:** My program is present in `test_script.py`, I want to access the `ConfigurationManager` class which is present in the file `config_manager.py`

I tried to put an `__init__.py` file in the `configs` with the following lines:

```
from . import configs
from .configs import *
```

**MWE:**

```
import numpy as np

# Config
from configs.config_manager import ConfigurationManager as cfg
```

The above code is throwing an exception:

> Exception has occurred: ModuleNotFoundError       (note: full exception trace is shown but execution is paused at: )
> No module named 'configs'
> File "D:\code\test_script.py", line 9, in  (Current frame)
> from configs.config_manager import ConfigurationManager as cfg
> ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'configs'

Answer (score 0):

To access the class, you need to ensure that the configs directory is in your Python path. You can achieve this by adding the parent directory (which contains both configs and simulation_scripts) to the Python path.

```
import sys
import os

# Add the parent directory to the Python path
sys.path.append(os.path.abspath(os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), '..')))
from configs.config_manager import ConfigurationManager as cfg
```

I think this should work for you.